# Why is the exec command used for file descriptor redirection?

Tags: shell

In UNIX shells like Bash and Korn shell `exec` is used for two specific uses.

Its use to replace the current program with another, as in `exec prog` is understandable.  The name `exec` is a contraction from the C family of routines based on `execve`.

If I was writing a shell and I wanted a command to open a file then I would probably call it `open`, but no, Bash and Korn shells use `exec` again, as in `exec 3<file`, for example.

Why was the `exec` command reused for something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really completely different: you can use redirections *with* an command

```
bash -c 'exec date > date.out' ; cat date.out
```

Why not use it without a command

```
bash -c 'exec > date.out; date' ; cat date.out
```

Comment: I had  never considered the exec command in that way, even though I have been using it for over 20 years.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 4 years late to the party but I've just been looking at this myself.

Just note that you need to be careful with Glenn's answer, because in the case where you use exec with both a command and redirection, the result is just the redirection.

The supposedly 'exec'd' command will run in a subshell, and commands after it in the calling script will still run.

Which to me suggests that the two uses really should be two separate commands.

Comment: (1) Perhaps I misunderstand what you’re saying, but I can’t reproduce what I think you’re saying in bash 4.1.  I did `exec date > date.out` in a script, and commands after it in the script did not run.  (2) This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: So far as I can tell the exec'd command does not occur in a sub-shell but in the same process, unless you have evidence that it is a sub-shell.  I also tried to reproduce this and got the same results as @Scott in bash 3.2 and 4.4.  To quote the source code (`builtins/exec.def`) *Replace the shell with the given command.

Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
ARGUMENTS become the arguments to COMMAND.  If COMMAND is not specified,
any redirections take effect in the current shell.*

Comment: To answer Scott's point 2 - I don't have the reputation to be able to comment so I added an answer - I'm not sure whether that's an approved of thing or not..  I see what you mean with your date example. I was debugging a script that did something like `exec date | tee date.out` and that behaves differently. If you exec a script that prints $$ this way you can see you get a new shell. So it looks like a pipe works differently. I was kind of looking it as the same thing but I guess a pipe includes redirection but is more than just redirection.